# JAXB getter with validation possible?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

My code looks like this:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "Elements", namespace = MyNamespaceContext.NS_SOME, 
propOrder = { "element" })
public class Elements implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@XmlElement(required = true)
protected List<Element> element;

public List<element> getElement() {
    if (element == null) {
        element = new ArrayList<Element>();
    }
    //Added by me afterwards
    element = ElementHelper.normalizeElement(element);
    return this.element;
}
```

}

The XML for that looks like that:

```
<elements>
    <element>
        <one>something</one>
        <two>something</two>
    </element>
    <element>
        <one>another </one>
        <two>another</two>
    </element>
</elements>
```

What I would like to do is to add a cleaner to my getter method to remove whitespaces and stuff. So I thought about adding my `ElementHelper` to the getter (see code snippet). But it does not work (still whitespaces in my output). If I call `Elements.getElement()` somewhere in my code and use the returned list with the `ElementHelper` it does work. So it seems to me, that the getter method is not called as it should.

Would it help to move the `XmlElement` to the getter method? Or is there some other simple trick to do this kind of stuff?

I would like to do this at this part of the code (centralized) because I don't want to call the `ElementHelper` every time it is needed in all kinds of places in the code and forget it at some other places (it's legacy code). Or do one of you have a suggestion where to do this instead? Because I don't like doing this in a getter.

I just started learning about JAXB and a lot is still not clear to me. If you could answer in more detail about how JAXB works in that matter or point to a good and understandable source, I would appreciate it.

**EDIT:**

Here the code for the ElementHelper:

```
public static List<Element> normalizeElement(List<Element> elements){
    for(int i = 0; i < elements.size(); i++){
        normalizeValues(elements.get(i));
    }
    return elements;
}

private static void normalizeValues(Element element){
    String one;
    String two;
    if( (one = element.getOne()) != null){
        element.setOne(one.trim());
        element.setOne(one.replaceAll("\\s+", ""));
    }

    if( (two = element.getTwo()) != null){
        element.setTwo(two.trim());
        element.setTwo(two.replaceAll("\\s+", ""));     
    }

}
```

The desired output is, that the strings for One and Two will have no whitespaces and other non-visible characters.

Comment: Can you post the ElementHelper? Also post the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you use `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)` jaxb will access the fields directly, use `PROPERTY` or `NONE` and move the annotations to the getter.
2. The `List` will be empty for the first call to `getElement`, so nothing to normalize. i'm not sure if it will be called a second time.

I would use the `void afterUnmarshal(Unmarshaller u, Object parent)` method to normalize everything in the class once it is completely setup.

Something like that should do:

```
void afterUnmarshal(Unmarshaller u, Object parent) {
    this.element = ElementHelper.normalizeElement(element);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try that. I read about this callback method, but wasn't sure how to use it. What I don't get is what it means when you say "jaxb will access the fields directly".

Comment: If you use `@XmlAccessorType(FIELD)` jaxb will not use the getters/setters to access the fields. It will use reflection to access them directly (even if private)